# How to apply a function in between elements of a two columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function which takes two tuple inputs.for example:

```
def mult((x1,y1),(x2,y2)):
    return Eucledeandist((x1,y1),(x2,y2))
```

I have a dataframe with two columns (x,y), where x and y represents coordinates of a point. Now i need to calculate the distance from every point to every other point in the dataframe. 
I mean if the length of df is 'n'. I need a a output of size nXn where (i,j)th entry is the distance between i th and jth point in the original dataframe.

How can i use df.apply function to do this rather than having two for loops?

Sample code to generate the dataframe similar to what i have

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.randint(10, size=6), 'y':np.random.randint(10, size=6)})
df['(x,y)']=list(zip(df.x, df.y))
```

dataframe should like this

```
    x   y   (x,y)
0   9   4   (9, 4)
1   8   6   (8, 6)
2   8   4   (8, 4)
3   1   7   (1, 7)
4   7   1   (7, 1)
5   0   5   (0, 5)
```

column (x,y) is just columns x and y zipped together. I felt it would be easy as the function takes tuple input.

edit: I apologize for not specifying it clearly. I used Euclidean distance just as an example to simplify my requirement. The actual requirement is that function should be used to get the result. what ever the function does is not really important.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add DataFrame too

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, no need for for loops or apply, which are really slow.

You can use a vectorized solution instead based on the Euclidean distance formula

```
np.sqrt(((df.values - df.values[:,None])**2).sum(2))
```

---

MCVE

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3,4], 'y':[10,20,30,40]})

    x   y
0   1   10
1   2   20
2   3   30
3   4   40
```

Yields

```
array([[ 0.        , 10.04987562, 20.09975124, 30.14962686],
       [10.04987562,  0.        , 10.04987562, 20.09975124],
       [20.09975124, 10.04987562,  0.        , 10.04987562],
       [30.14962686, 20.09975124, 10.04987562,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it using the function defined?

Comment: @subhash you would lose the vectorization power, i.e. your solution would become way slower

Comment: it is important to call the function. I just asked euclidean distance to simplify my requirement. I made an edit to question to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) and [`squareform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html) from `scipy.spacial.distance` module:

#### Example

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

euc_dist = pdist(df[['x', 'y']])
df_dist = pd.DataFrame(squareform(euc_dist), index=df['(x,y)'], columns=df['(x,y)'])

print(df_dist)

(x,y)     (9, 4)    (8, 6)    (8, 4)    (1, 7)    (7, 1)    (0, 5)
(x,y)                                                             
(9, 4)  0.000000  2.236068  1.000000  8.544004  3.605551  9.055385
(8, 6)  2.236068  0.000000  2.000000  7.071068  5.099020  8.062258
(8, 4)  1.000000  2.000000  0.000000  7.615773  3.162278  8.062258
(1, 7)  8.544004  7.071068  7.615773  0.000000  8.485281  2.236068
(7, 1)  3.605551  5.099020  3.162278  8.485281  0.000000  8.062258
(0, 5)  9.055385  8.062258  8.062258  2.236068  8.062258  0.000000
```

If you insist on using `.apply`, then you would need to structure it like:

```
def mult(xy1, xy2):
    return Eucledeandist(xy1, xy2)

import itertools

df_coords = pd.DataFrame([[x, y] for x, y in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(df['(x,y)'], 2)], columns=['xy1', 'xy2'])
df_coords.apply(lambda row: mult(row['xy1'], row['xy2']) , axis=1)
```

Although, as has alread been pointed out, this is very inefficient and not recommended.

Comment: Is it possible to do it using the function defined?